# Rapid structured data-to-text in Scala: JSON or XML, and which?

Tags: xml, json, scala, serialization

I have vast amounts of data that, once lightly processed, I would like to store in a marginally readable ASCII format.  Because of the volume of data, the speed of input and output is extremely important to me.  (Most of it will be `Float` data in arrays, but there will be some simple data structures and short descriptive text strings also.  Unicode support is not important.)

Aside from rolling my own idiosyncratic format, my best options in Scala seem to be some sort of XML or JSON format.  My primary considerations are:

1. Speed -- should be fast enough so that this is not the bottleneck in processing
2. Small footprint -- I don't want to add gigantic dependencies if possible
3. Straightforward -- I'll be asking for simple operations; I don't want to spend a long time configuring or massaging data or anything; just data out, data in.  (I'm happy packing the parsed data into my own data structures; it needn't worry about that.)

Which library best meets these criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) was for me a fast and simple to use library. You can either parse text to a JSON AST or map the data to your model-specific data structures - [see here](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) more examples. Of course, it also supports serializing your data to JSON

You can make Jackson Scala friendly in two ways AFAIK:

- Use the Scala module found here: [Jackson Scala Module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala). This will map JSON data to Scala specific data structures (automatically handle case classes, convert nulls to options, etc.)
- Use [Jerkson](https://github.com/codahale/jerkson/) - this is a wrapper library over Jackson. It is also used for handling JSON in the Play Framework

Personally, I used Jackson with the Scala module to serialize/deserialize my case class to JSON with stellar results - so I definitely recommend it.